# How $watch works in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, directive, watch

I did a custom directive to change the sentence to edit box, but how it jump back when there's no input?

This is my HTML:

```
<name ng-hide="!custom1" my-text="name" placeholder="jhkiii" class="des"</name>       
       <a href="#"  ng-click="custom1=!custom1" ng-hide="custom1">
       Select to add a description 1<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
       </a><br>
         <name ng-hide="!custom2" my-text="desc" placeholder="asdfasd" class="des">
          </name>       
   <a href="#"  ng-click="custom2=!custom2" ng-hide="custom2">
   Select to add a description 2<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
```

This is my angularjs code:

```
.directive("name",function(){
  return{
    restrict:"E", 
    /*scope:{
      text:'=placeholder'
    },*/

    scope:{

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myClass=attrs['class'];
      console.log(scope.myClass);
      scope.placeholder=attrs['placeholder'];
},

    template:'<input type="text"  autofocus placeholder="{{placeholder}}" class="{{myClass}}"/>',
    controller: function($scope){
        /*$scope.$watch("name", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length <= 0) {
      alert("nothing change");
    }
  });*/
   }
  }
```

This is the output:

```
Select to add a description 1 
Select to add a description 2
```

After click the link, it will change to input box, but when there's no input, it is loss focus, it will jump back to the "Select to add a description 1" this link. I think I should use $watch, but not sure how, or you have any ideas, please help me. Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this directive, exactly? your custom element is adding an `<input>` which isn't bound to any property on scope and doesn't have any value.  Why not just use a regular `<input>` in your HTML with `ng-class`, instead of this directive? or is the directive doing something else that you aren't showing?

Comment: also, you can't use `$scope` inside your directive controller the way you are trying here, because you created the directive with an isolate scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I use directive because I need use the custom function in a lot of places. If my custom directive works, I can just use the tag in everywhere.

Comment: This is my link: http://codepen.io/AceSai/pen/QjWGYq

Comment: it's still not clear what you are trying to accomplish with this directive; what do you want that input to be used for? right now, you are rendering an input that doesn't do anything.   neither of the things you are trying to set (placeholder, class) are complex enough that a directive would be necessary, and creating a directive "just to have a directive" doesn't reduce your app complexity or make it more usable.  You don't have any custom function in your demo code.

Comment: this is definitely a case of the XY problem, you are trying to ask how to fix a potential solution to an unknown problem, and your code here isn't a complete representation of anything at all.